# Voting to close a question, within a question, does not count towards your review total

Tags: discussion, badges, vote-to-close

Today I realized that if I am in a question and I vote to close it, for whatever reason (and I am not the first person to vote to close the question), it doesn't count towards my review count. That means that those close votes don't go towards your Custodian/Reviewer/Steward badge count.

In order for it to count towards your tally, the vote to close has to be from within the Close Votes within the review dashboard.

Is this correct or should it be changed?

It seems to me that peoples effort, to close bad posts as they see them, goes unrewarded. These peoples effort should not be disregarded.

Note: I am sure this is not isolated to Arduino and happens on all SE sites. I have searched SE meta but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a little confused by "if I am in a question and I vote to close it" but I take it you mean arriving at the question from outside of a review queue.

If so, then yes, this is correct, and you're right, this is network-wide behavior. The intent of the Custodian, Reviewer and Steward badges is first to increase awareness that the review queues exist, and then encourage people to spend time there/reward those who choose to give back to the community in that particular way. They're not so much about the specific actions one can take from the queues, although there are other badges that cover some of those, like Vox Populi and Copy Editor.

The absence of a badge for closing questions is by design; it would result in many spurious close votes from people just trying to get shiny pieces of virtual metal. Closing questions isn't a primary feature here anyways; it's just something that was invented to assist in keeping things tidy while we work on the real goal: making the Internet a better place through Q&A.

Comment: wrote "I take it you mean arriving at the question from outside of a review queue." - Correct.